# What makes node.js SlowBuffers "slow"?

Tags: performance, node.js, buffer

I'm using [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) to serve some PNG images that are stored in an SQLite database as binary BLOBs. These images are small, on average 9500 bytes.

I'm using [the sqlite3 npm package](https://npmjs.org/package/sqlite3), which appears to return binary BLOB objects as [`SlowBuffers`](http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_slowbuffer). My node.js service holds these `SlowBuffers` in memory to mitigate IO latency, serving them like this:

```
response.send(slowBuffer);
```

It appears that `SlowBuffer` has an interface similar to `Buffer`; converting to `Buffer` is trivial:

```
var f = function(slowBuffer) {
  var buffer = new Buffer(slowBuffer.length);
  slowBuffer.copy(buffer);
  return buffer;
}
```

**Should I convert these `SlowBuffers` to `Buffers`?**

**Help me understand why they are called "slow" buffers.**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you would read the posts:

1. https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/nodejs-dev/jd52ZsVSZNo
2. https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/nodejs/s1dnFbb-Rj8

Node provides two types of buffer objects. `Buffer` is a native Javascript data structure; `SlowBuffer` is implemented by a C++ module. Using C++ modules from the native Javascript environment costs extra CPU time, hence the "slow". `Buffer` objects are backed by `SlowBuffer` objects, but the contents can be read/written directly from Javascript for better performance.

Any `Buffer` object larger than 8 KB is backed by a single `SlowBuffer` object. Multiple `Buffer` objects smaller than 8 KB can be backed by a single `SlowBuffer` object. When many `Buffer` objects smaller than 8 KB exist in memory (backed by a single `SlowBuffer`), the C++ module penalty can be very high if you were to instead use a `SlowBuffer` for each one. Small `Buffers` are often used in large quantities.

[`This class is primarily for internal use`](http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_slowbuffer) means that if you want to manage buffers on the server on your own, then use `SlowBuffer` (to use in smaller chunks you have to partition `SlowBuffer` yourself). Unless you want that minute level control in handling buffers, you should be fine with using `Buffer` objects.

Comment: If the data in a `Buffer` is just using `SlowBuffer` anyway, then why the difference?  Is it that there are pre-allocated `SlowBuffer`s?

Comment: Both are memory allocations alright but Buffer uses native JS functions to manipulate the memory, whereas SlowBuffer uses external C++ API. There is an overhead when you call C++ API from node.js.

Comment: Does `Buffer` only use `SlowBuffer` when the memory needed is over 8K?  That is in conflict with, "each buffer is in fact backed by SlowBuffer", which is where I am confused.

Comment: I meant when the number of buffers (having size less than 8KB) is large (which is very common). By "it is not feasible to handle it" I mean to say performance will be slower, depending on how much  buffers you use. It will hurt if your server handles a lot of buffers.

Comment: Buffer can have any size. If buffer is less than 8KB it is backed by SlowBuffer, and does not use external API. I was considering buffers less than 8KB. I will change that line.

Comment: When size < 8KB Buffer derives address space from SlowBuffer (created implicitly). One SlowBuffer can back many Buffers.
When size > 8KB a Buffer uses SlowBuffer itself (not backing, since both are same). @Jacob changes are correct.

Comment: @user568109 I think my last edit captures what you have shared here. If anyone can provide further insight, or references to canonical statements, code, etc, please feel free.

Comment: What do you think, @Brad? I believe this answer is pretty good, though it's tough to find hard references with node.js.

Comment: @JacobMarble, It's becoming more clear, but I am still confused.  Just to clarify... no matter what size, if I use a Buffer, it is backed by a SlowBuffer.  Buffers over 8KB have their own SlowBuffer.  Buffers smaller than 8KB can potentially share a SlowBuffer with other Buffers.  Now, if I do Buffer operations, such as copying from one Buffer to another, is the implementation handled by the C++ module?  Or does the data have to come out of the SlowBuffer, be passed to JavaScript, work done on it, and then sent back to the C++ module?

Comment: @Brad The C++ module is not used when using Buffer , the procedure route you mention about handling buffer is what happens when using SlowBuffer. Difference between Buffer/SlowBuffer is how they access the allocated memory. When Buffer operations are called, no external C++ API is called.

Comment: @user568109 Then why the performance penalty when there are many Buffers <8KB?

Comment: @JacobMarble It was in context of your comment about how bad will it hurt, if you used SlowBuffer instead of Buffer. If you use Buffers in large numbers, penalty will be high if you use SLowBuffer instead.

Comment: @user568109, I still don't follow.  I guess I will just read through the source code later and figure it out.

Comment: @user568109 I'm not quite sure what you mean by "external C++ API". JavaScript isn't like a normal language where you "marshal" things between the native and managed world. All the internals of JavaScript ARE C++ meaning that there is no difference in calling a "native" JavaScript function and a C++ function. Both are implemented (or JITed) to a C++ function anyway and are invoked almost identically. I'd say for memory operations, being able to use native memory functions would WELL outweigh the "overhead" of calling into C++ land, especially considering the overhead is 0.

Comment: @jduncanator I don't understand what you mean you say both are JITed. C++ is compiled and JS is interpreted. You could also use C++ dynamic libraries, but still it would not be optimized like you said. Only the JS can be JITed. If it wraps a C++ function it would be compiled one not interpreted at runtime. This is the first instance I've heard that overhead is 0. If you have any evidence please show it, because many people have said otherwise. Remember it is not simple C++ call, there is a context change happening.

Comment: @user568109 v8 compiles most of the JavaScript down to raw assembly. The speed at which invocations occurs into those compiled JavaScript functions has little to no overhead. Whilst I admit saying 0 overhead is wrong, the amount of overhead you are seeing is much much much smaller than most other languages that do marshalling.

Comment: @jduncanator My mistake. You are right, when you asked about external C++ API I mistook them to be addons, which are shown to be slower. But there are no addons here, everything is compiled into node itself. In my defense I answered it more than a year back. To be clear the overhead are the extra calls (in case of SlowBuffer) happening C++ to allocate memory. SlowBuffers are separate chunks of memory each with separate calls and Buffers is a way of saving those calls. See the last comment on https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/4525

Comment: @user568109 All cool. I know it was an old thread but thought I'd just leave my opinion.